# Updates in CQL-engine

Tags: django, orm, cassandra, cql, cqlengine

I use Cassandra with Django via cqlengine. Let's assume I have a model like this:

```
class ExampleModel(Model):
    example_id      = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    example_types   = columns.List(columns.Integer)
    example_other   = columns.Integer()
```

I create an object using the following code:

```
ex = ExampleModel.create(example_types=[1,2,3])
```

Somewhere else I want to update this row (eg. add some value to example_other) knowing it's example_id:

```
ex2 = ExampleModel.create(example_id=<this id I know>, example_other=5)
```

In the old version of cqlengine (0.4.6) it used to work, that is example_types stored in the database used to contain [1,2,3]. After an upgrade to 0.8.5 and after creating ex2, the same object stored in database has example_types set to an empty list. I understand that this is probably cleaner, but I want to be able to update row (alter particular column without altering rest of them) without having to fetch it first. How to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Facing same problem. Are you able to solve it? Please update if you have found anything. Thanks.

Comment: Since 0.9 it's been fixed AFAIR

Answer (score 1):

You can perform [blind updates](http://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html#cqlengine.query.QuerySet.update) in cqlengine.

```
MyModel.objects(id=1).update(name="Steve")
```